# Builder (#2) for pdf output format has an invalid configuration:

Tags: pdftex, texlipse, eclipse

I am using eclipse cppMars, and I have installed texlipse.

But I am getting error when I want to see the output: **Builder (#2) for pdf output format has an invalid configuration:**

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: You need a separate plugin like Pdf4Eclipse, a pdf reader plugin for Eclipse. Without this eclipse doesn't know how to open read or present the pdf.

Comment: @EngBIRD Did not help me on [my issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635523/builder-2-for-pdf-output-format-has-an-invalid-configuration) unfortunately.

Comment: yusuf, where you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Also, Have you checked that your tmp files are cleaned up when you try a build with the automatic builder? I've never had a problem with tmp files and conflicts in any latex builder, Texlipse included, unless the project is in dropbox and the files are getting locked. Similarly, LaTeX can't build a pdf if your pdf is open in a pdf reader. Evince (and possibly some others) don't need to close the document to refresh the file, but adobe locks the file, so make sure your file isn't open (a file indexer could also, conceivably, open the file)